# mysql custom order by query on same table

Tags: mysql

I have data like and it have more columns not only below two:

```
id       |  s_type
1        |  ACTIVE
2        |  PENDING
3        |  UPDATE
4        |  ACTIVE
5        |  PENDING
6        |  UPDATE
```

I used order by ASC, DESC but i want to display  data with custom order and i want to show it as my custom orders  (not only asc or descending): want to see first all PENDING then all ACTIVE then all UPDATE s_type

```
id       |  s_type
1        |  PENDING
2        |  PENDING
3        |  ACTIVE
4        |  ACTIVE
5        |  UPDATE
6        |  UPDATE
```

How can i display with single query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY field(s_type, 'PENDING', 'ACTIVE', 'UPDATE'), id
```

Or use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CASE s_type WHEN 'PENDING' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN 3 END, id
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it works:

```
      SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY 
    s_type = 'UPDATE',
signal_status = 'ACTIVE',
signal_status = 'PENDING'
```